# WPF Datagrid validation through parent viewmodel using INotifyDataErrorInfo

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, fluentvalidation

Let's say my viewmodel class looks like that

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ValidatableBindableBase
{
   public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; } = new 
                                            ObservableCollection<Employee>();
}
```

where Employee class is

```
public class Employee : ValidatableBindableBase
{
        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get => _name;
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _name, value);
            }
        }

        private int _age;
        public int Age
        {
            get => _age;
            set => SetProperty(ref _age, value);
        }
}
```

The main view contains a datagrid which binds to the observable collection. Now I am using FluentValidatin to perform the validation logic and I have two options: 1) Validate on the employee class level, or 2) Mainwindow class level. If we go with the second option, the validation will be something like this:

```
internal class EmployeeValidation : AbstractValidator<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeValidation()
    {
        RuleFor(e => e.Age).ExclusiveBetween(10, 50);
    }
}

internal class MainWindowValidation : AbstractValidator<MainWindowViewModel>
{
    public MainWindowValidation()
    {
        RuleForEach(x => x.Employees).SetValidator(new EmployeeValidation());
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is the validation result shows the property name as "Employees[0].Age" which obviously doesn't work properly with datagrid binding. I am aware that if I run the validation on the Employee class level the property name will be "Age" and INotifyDataErrorInfo works fine. However, I prefer to work with parent viewmodel (i.e. MainWindow), is there a way to resolve the property name issue?

Comment: If your issue with option (2) is the format of the message, you could providing a [custom message](https://fluentvalidation.net/start#configuring) or property name.  I can't give you a definitive answer, as I've never used that Fluent Validation framework.

Comment: @MikeStrobel, what should be the appropriate property name? Please note that this is a nested property (i.e. Age property is a member of Employee class not the mainwindow)

Comment: Like I said, I've never used this framework, so I'm not sure.  Read the documentation and do some experimentation.